# Microsoft Access 2010 Append query error

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, append

I have the following sql which returns the records i need correctly.

```
INSERT INTO Historic 
SELECT * FROM current 
  LEFT JOIN Historic ON (current.aptdat = Historic.aptdat) 
  AND (current.ordnum = Historic.ordnum) 
  AND (current.type = Historic.type) 
  AND (current.itmcod = Historic.itmcod)
WHERE (Historic.aptdat & Historic.ordnum & Historic.type) Is Null 
 AND current.ordnum is not null;
```

The problem is when i try to run it as an append query, i get the error **

> Duplicate output destination 'APTDAT'

**

What am i missing ?

PS: the last line of the code is to ensure records from the 'current' table, which is a linked excel sheet, are not returned if they just contain blank rows. Not including the line means 800 rows are returned, but only 3 contain data !

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT *` gives all columns of all tables in the FROM clause. So you get all columns of `Historic` too, and since this also has a column `aptdat`, you get the error.

Solution: Use `<table>.*`

```
INSERT INTO Historic 
SELECT current.* FROM current 
  LEFT JOIN Historic ON ...
```